# Android studio text to speech speak failed: not bound to TTS engine

Tags: java, android

I tried to follow a tutorial for a basic text to speech app but kept getting speak failed: not bound to TTS engine error
Anyone experience this before or knows what to do?

MainActivity.java file

```
`package com.example.texttospeechtest;

import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import android.view.View;

import androidx.core.view.WindowCompat;
import androidx.navigation.NavController;
import androidx.navigation.Navigation;
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration;
import androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI;

import com.example.texttospeechtest.databinding.ActivityMainBinding;

import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText editText;
    Button buttonConvert;
    TextToSpeech textToSpeech;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        editText = findViewById(R.id.editText);
        buttonConvert = findViewById(R.id.buttonConvert);
        textToSpeech = new TextToSpeech(MainActivity.this, new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInit(int i) {

            }
        });

        buttonConvert.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                textToSpeech.speak(""+editText.getText().toString(), TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null,null);

            }
        });
    }

}

`
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:hint="Enter text"
        android:padding="40dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonConvert"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Convert"
        android:padding="10dp"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Above is the code I tried writing and the warning
2023-12-19 20:52:23.364 30896-30896 TextToSpeech            com.example.texttospeechtest         W  speak failed: not bound to TTS engine
I cant make the sdk version 29 or 28 because of Google Play requiring it to be at least 33

Answer (score 0):

You have to set a language:

```
    ...
    textToSpeech = new TextToSpeech(getApplicationContext(), new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
      @Override 
      public void onInit(int status) {
        textToSpeech.setLanguage(Locale.GERMAN);
      }
    });
    ...
    buttonConvert.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            textToSpeech("Willkommen");
        }
    });
    ...
```